# HttpRequestException - SendGrid Email API v3 integration on a 1&1 Ionos plan

Tags: c#, .net-core, httprequest, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I have had an integration problem when hosting my web application in production, and an unanswered support ticket with SendGrid that was created 5 days prior (at the time of writing this). 1&1 have assured me that all ports are open.

My SendGrid Email API (v3) is working perfectly well in development and when I deploy to a site on my network - I have been using an implementation similar to this: https://app.sendgrid.com/guide/integrate/langs/csharp.

When I deploy to my 1&1 Ionos webspace and test I receive the following error:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

I am starting to despair as this has caused something of a road block on a project of mine.

[EDIT]

I have just tried a httprequest using a different API and I get the same error. So it must be a server problem with 1&1, but what do I tell them?

Answer (score 1):

I proved the problem was with 1&1, not SendGrid, by testing with another API and getting the same error.
Turns out 1&1 hosting uses a proxy server and I need to amend my SendGrid integration to use a web proxy.
I discovered this:
http://tutorials.moedesign.de/blog/proxy-on-ionos-11-webhosting/

which led me to this help provided by 1&1:
https://www.ionos.co.uk/help/hosting/net/script-examples-for-establishing-external-http-connections-windows/

Quite why they couldn't inform me of this when I rang for support is beyond me.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet for this, i have tried adding the proxy to the web config but the error is still being thrown. Did you have to edit your SendGridClient code?

Answer (score 0):

This post is old and I am using ionos 1&1 this was my solution to get around the proxy issue.  I hope this helps someone out

```
#if !DEBUG
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("http://winproxyus1.1and1.com:3128"),
        UseProxy = true,
        AllowAutoRedirect = true
    };
    var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    var sendGridClient = new SendGridClient(apiKey: SendGridSecret, httpClient: httpClient);
    var client = sendGridClient;
    var from = new EmailAddress("Email Address Here", "Subject Here");
    var to = new EmailAddress(email);
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, "", htmlMessage);

    return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

#else

```
    var client = new SendGridClient(SendGridSecret);
    var from = new EmailAddress("Email Address Here", "Subject Here");
    var to = new EmailAddress(email);
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, "", htmlMessage);

    return client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

#endif

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**